# React does not update values on another page

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 pages in my application: `/home` and `/about`.
I set a simple counter on `Home.js` component. Also i dispatch the action every time when i count, and in this way i update the state in my `store`. 
The code works, and i can access the value from my store, but the problem is in `About.js` component, because when i access the value from store, from this component, i get just the first value of counter which is equal with `0`, but when i click on count button from `Home.js` component, the value is changing only in home page not in about page where the value is equall every time with `0`.

**Question**: How to update the value in about page, clicking on counter from home page?

Comment: can you paste the code?

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest you use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

because to understand the problem without code is really hard for us.

I have a few questions & suggestions:
1. Is your page refreshing while you navigate to /About page because the store is not persistent unless you make it?
2. Try using [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger) to track the state updates on every action.

Please let me add this as an answer because I don't have access to comment

Just add Link on the home page that would route to the about page and try increasing the value and click on that link. 
The about page will have the same value as home page.

```
<div className="App">
   <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: COUNTER })}>click</button>
   <h1>Nr: {selector.counter}</h1>
   <Link to="/about">About Us</Link>
</div>
```

Comment: i try to get the state when i have open both pages. So, i have `home` page opened and also `about` page is opened in my browser. When i click on counter i get the state only in home page, but not in about. I don't want to make a refersh of my page browser, i expect the state in about page without referesching

Comment: I got that, can you please take time and post a code sample that would resolve this faster I promise.

Comment: here i added some code: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hawking-wu1df?file=/src/App.js   . I want to achive next: i want to open both pages in browser. When i will count on main page, i want to get the updated value on `/about` route, without refreshing.

Comment: Let me understand you have home page opened in one tab and about page opened in another tab and when a state is updated on the homepage you want it to updated in the about page as well?

Comment: I have updated the answer please try that and let me know.
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cdn-8wv72